# Using packets gotten from devices connected to an android device's hotspot interface

Tags: android, sockets, networking, packets

I created a VPN using android's VPNService class. Now, I want this VPN to also handle packets from the device's hotspot interface. So in the VPNService Builder, I called the addRoute("0.0.0.0",0). This made sure I got all outgoing packets including the Hotspot.

The problem I am currently facing is that when I get packets redirected from the hotspot, the packets seem to still have IPs from the hotspot network. 192.168.43.... both in the source field and destination fields of the IP packets and the payload doesn't seem to contain a TCP packet either.

My questions are:
Why does the hotspot packet I receive from the VPN interface not have the same source IP as that of the VPN interface created by VPNService class?

Is there another layer the packets from the hotspot are packaged for since I can't seem to get a remote Address for the real request in the IP headers?

Is my VPNInterface setup wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interface was setup correctly.

Apparently, what I was getting then were DHCP packets. DHCPOFFER Packets from Android's Local DHCP Servers.

Even though android's VPN interface is setup to get all outgoing packets on a device, it doesn't seem to get broadcast packets but for some reason, it gets replies to broadcast packets.

I wonder why it was designed that way.

Understanding this helped me solve my problem.